# iframe html page with flash content create problem for drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash

I have an iframe to a page where a Flash swf file is running; does anybody have an idea how to make it transparent so that my drop-down menu should be shown perfectly? Kindly be informed I can't edit the source page (add `param = wmode, value = transparent` to the Flash object), only if there is any chance to make it possible in iframe or some JavaScript on my page, I have already tried `allowtransparency="true"` and `background-color="transparent"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the flash containing div temporarily while the menu is open. Use javascript to set the `flashDiv.style.display = "none";` when the menu opens and set it back to `flashDiv.style.display = "block"` when menu is closed.

Comment: +1 - That's an interesting idea. But switching the `style.display` property of an element can cause the page to reflow. You might want to toggle the `style.visibility` property instead (between "hidden" and "visible").

Answer (score 0):

sorry, but there is no way to do that.
unless you have control on the page showing the page and add the wmode=transparent param.
this is one of the biggest problems since flash was out on the web.
what you could do, is write an email to the owner of the flash page, and kindly ask him to add that param.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to increase the value of the `style.zIndex` property of your drop-down menu, so that it could appear in front of the iframe even if it is not transparent. But it's just an idea, I don't know if it will work.

To try this, as browsers ignore the `style.zIndex` property on non-positioned elements,  your drop-down menu should then have `style.position` with `"relative"` or `"absolute"`.

EDIT: I could see you are now trying to add a `makeWmode` function to your version of the swfobject.js. Of course I hope your code will work, but otherwise here is mine, if I can help you...

```
function makeWMode(id, mode) {  // id: the id of the <object> tag of the Flash object; in this case I think it is "content"
    var object = swfobject.getObjectById(id);
    var params = object.getElementsByTagName("param");
    var success = false;
    for (var i = 0; i< params.length; i++) {
        if (params[i].name.toLowerCase() == "wmode") {
            params[i].value = mode;
            success = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (success == false) {
        var param = document.createElement("param");
        param.name = "wmode";
        param.value = "transparent";
        object.appendChild(param);
        success = true;
        return success;
    }
}
```

Using `makeWMode("content", "transparent")` added a tag `<param name="wmode" value="transparent">` to the `object` tag, but it may not work with an `embed` tag.

Answer (score 0):

The Code for index.html is like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="files/swfobject.js">//</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="files/swfaddress.js">//</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="files/facebook.js">//</script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

 var assetsFolder = 'assets';
  var mobileFolder = 'mobile';

  var changeURL = function(){
    if(document.getElementById('hrefMobile'))document.getElementById('hrefMobile').href = dir+mobileFolder+'/index.html';
    if(document.getElementById('hrefSEO'))document.getElementById('hrefSEO').href = dir+assetsFolder +'/seo/toc.html';
    delete changeURL;
  }
  if (document.addEventListener){
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", changeURL, false);
} else {
document.attachEvent("onDOMContentLoaded", changeURL);
} 

  function afterLoad(){ 
    checkPage(); 
    setFocusOnFlash(); 
      }

  function setFocusOnFlash(){ 
        var f=swfobject.getObjectById('content');

                    if (f) { f.tabIndex = 0; f.focus(); } 

                  }
      function getURLParam()
      {
      var returnObject = {};
      var href = window.location.href;
      if ( href.indexOf("?") > -1 )
      {
      var param = href.substr(href.indexOf("?"));
               var arrayParam = param.split("&");
  returnObject['assets'] = assetsFolder;
      for ( var i = 0; i < arrayParam.length; i++ )
                {
                    var value = arrayParam[i].split("=");
                    returnObject[value[0]] = value[1];
                }
        }
        return returnObject;
    }
    var dir = "./files/";


     var getURI = function(){
            var URIArray = document.location.href.split('/');

             URIArray.length = URIArray.length-1;
            var URIstr = URIArray.join('/');

            URIArray = null;

            var URIarr = dir.split('/');
            URIarr[0] = URIarr[0]=='.'?'':URIarr[0];
            var dirStr = URIarr.join('/');

            URIstr = URIstr+dirStr;

        return URIstr;
        }



      var swfName = "flippingbook.swf?rnd=44c3b8c18caec0e3862101a6d4de273f";

     var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
      platform = navigator.platform.toLowerCase(),
      UA = ua.match(/(opera|ie|firefox|chrome|version)[\s\/:]([\w\d\.]+)?.*?(safari|version[\s\/:]([\w\d\.]+)|$)/) || [null, 'unknown', 0],
      mode = UA[1] == 'ie' && document.documentMode;

      var Browser = {
      extend: Function.prototype.extend,
      name: (UA[1] == 'version') ? UA[3] : UA[1],
      version: mode || parseFloat((UA[1] == 'opera' && UA[4]) ? UA[4] : UA[2]),
      Platform: {
      name: ua.match(/ip(?:ad|od|hone)/) ? 'ios' : (ua.match(/(?:webos|android|bada|symbian|palm|blackberry)/) || platform.match(/mac|win|linux/) || ['other'])[0]
      },
      Features: {
      xpath: !!(document.evaluate),
      air: !!(window.runtime),
      query: !!(document.querySelector),
      json: !!(window.JSON)
      },
      Plugins: {}
      };

      if(Browser.Platform.name == 'android' || Browser.Platform.name == 'ios') window.location = dir+mobileFolder+"/index.html";
      if(Browser.Platform.name == 'webos' || Browser.Platform.name == 'bada' || Browser.Platform.name == 'symbian' || Browser.Platform.name == 'palm' || Browser.Platform.name == 'blackberry') window.location = dir+assetsFolder+"/seo/page1.html";

      var flashvars = getURLParam();

     var params = {baseURI: getURI(), base: dir, allowFullScreen: true, allowScriptAccess: "sameDomain", quality: "high", scale: "noscale",bg:"transparent" };

      var attributes = {align: "middle" };

      swfobject.embedSWF(dir + swfName, "content", "100%", "100%", "10.0.0", dir + "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);



      </script>
```